How to create a custom JSX component with contentlayer?
I tried to create a custom component with contentlayer, but it was not working as expected. At first, I thought that I have to import the custom component inside the .mdx file and things will work just fine. But, it turned out that, that's not the case. What I needed to do was to place the component in an object that is assigned to a variable, then pass that variable as prop to the component returned from the useMDXComponent hook, then call the custom component directly in my .mdx file without importing it.
A practical example is shared below.

// page.tsx

import { useMDXComponent } from "next-contentlayer/hooks";

const Button = () => {
  return <button>Click me</button>;
};

const customComponents = {
  Button
};


const SinglePost = ({ article }) => {

  const MDXContent = useMDXComponent(article.body.code);

  return (
    <>
      <MDXContent components={customComponents} />
    </>
  );
};

// file.mdx

### Call Button directly in your mdx file. No need to import it, it works automatically.

<Button />


